# Find an edge that is completely visible from point outside a polygon (Convex Hull)

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, search-algorithms, polygons

I want to implement algorithms from this paper:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.5609&rep=rep1&type=pdf

In particular, I am currently dealing with the one in section 2.2.1. In page 4 (first paragraph), one algorithm step is as follows:

Find an edge $(v_k, v_{k+1})$ of $P_i$ ($P_i$ is a convex hull) that is completely visible from $s_i$ ($s_i$ is a point outside the convex hull).

My question is, how can I find a completely visible edge of a convex hull, that is completely visible from a point outside the convex hull?

Comment: If the two ends of an edge is visible, the the whole edge is visible. To check if $v_k$ is visible from $s_i$, you need to check if line segment $s_iv_k$ intersects with any of the edges (other than $v_kv_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too hard. connect the point to the end-point of an edge. If none of these two segments has an intersection with convex-hull, it means you can see that edge completely (as you consider a convex polygon).

To find the intersection, you can use a binary search and find that is there any intersection or not.

Comment: Or just search linearly (rather than a binary search). The code is simpler and unless your polygon has millions of vertices, it may be faster.